# Java: how to add image to Jlabel?

Tags: java, image, jlabel

```
Image image = GenerateImage.toImage(true); //this generates an image file
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(image)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to supply to the JLabel an `Icon` implementation (i.e `ImageIcon`). You can do it trough the `setIcon` method, as in your question, or through the `JLabel` constructor:

```
Image image=GenerateImage.toImage(true);  //this generates an image file
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

I recommend you to read the Javadoc for [`JLabel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), [`Icon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html), and [`ImageIcon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). Also, you can check the [How to Use Labels Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), for more information.

Answer (score 25):

To get an image from a URL we can use the following code:

```
ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon(PicURL));

jLabel2.setIcon(imgThisImg);
```

It totally works for me. The PicUrl is a string variable which strores the url of the picture.

Answer (score 12):

(If you are using NetBeans IDE) 
Just create a folder in your project but out side of src folder. Named the folder Images. And then put the image into the Images folder and write code below.

```
// Import ImageIcon     
ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("Images/YourCompanyLogo.png");
// In init() method write this code
jLabelYourCompanyLogo.setIcon(iconLogo);
```

Now run your program.

Answer (score 4):

the shortest code is :

```
JLabel jLabelObject = new JLabel();
jLabelObject.setIcon(new ImageIcon(stringPictureURL));
```

**stringPictureURL** is **PATH** of image .

Answer (score 1):

Simple code that you can write in ***main(String[] args)*** function

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//application will be closed when you close frame
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLocation(200,200);

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    if(fc.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());//it must be an image file, otherwise you'll get an exception
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);//showing up the frame
```