# Can I set jLabel´s text as symbols?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, symbols, epsilon

I have jFrame, many components there, jLabel too. I want set jLabel text not as string or through picture as icon. But as symbol (epsilon). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  You can use a Unicode escape sequence for this.  A lower-case epsilon is `"\u03B5"`.

There are plenty of charts of Unicode escape sequences online, to help you find other symbols.  There's also a really good tool at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/ where you can search for a symbol by name, and see exactly how to insert it in your Java.

There are some excellent answers on [Why does Java permit escaped unicode characters in the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4448180/) that describe advantages of this approach.

Comment: Or OP can probably just put an ε character in the code since java interpret source code as utf-8 IIRC.

Comment: Yes, if she can type it; and if she can guarantee that her IDE is set up to save files in UTF-8.  I find using the escape sequence to be safer.  You could post your suggestion as an answer though @SylvainDefresne

Comment: I was thinking too complicated. Such a simple solution I did not expect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code: YOUR_JLABEL_NAME.setText("Ɛ");

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a picture for jLabel. Check this url:
[set Icon to a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182329/how-to-set-icon-to-a-jlabel-from-an-image-from-a-folder)

Besides you can check this url too :[Java: how to add image to Jlabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775373/java-how-to-add-image-to-jlabel)

For your Problem: Just download the image epsilon(Any image according to the your requirement) and place it in a image folder, from that folder you can easily set the image for jlabel.