# Java Swing - Component to be used to display friend list with their images?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, actually i want to display **friend list** with their images in swing app.
which component should i use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `JList`

[image: List][image: List]

or `JTable` to achieve this.

[image: Table]

Take a look [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: As outlined in [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Try JLabel.

```
Image image = GenerateImage.toImage(true); //this generates an image file
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(image)
```

See this page for more guidance:
[Java: how to add image to Jlabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775373/java-how-to-add-image-to-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `JList` or a `JTable`.