# Inserting an image as a label in java

Tags: java, image, label

```
label_007= new JLabel("My Label");
```

In lieu of the above Label, `My Label` I want to insert an image in the same position. 
How can I do that? I am just a novice in Java.
 Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to add image to Jlabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775373/java-how-to-add-image-to-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon('image.png');
JLabel image = new JLabel();
image.setIcon(icon);
```

The above code should work.

1. Make an image icon with an image file
2. Make a JLabel
3. Then set your JLabel's Icon

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageIcon` for images:

```
ImageIcon ICON = new ImageIcon(URLClassLoader.class.getResource(IMAGE_PATH));
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
imageLabel.setIcon(ICON);
```

URLClassLoader.class.getResource is using for packaging the application in runnable-jar file.
The IMAGE_PATH is relative to your project folders/packages. for example if the image is in com.app.images package, the path will be /com/app/images/image.png.

If you're novice in Java and particularly in Swing, I encourage you to check my swing projects- [Minesweeper](https://github.com/lidanh/SouthParkMinesweeper) and [Pacman](https://github.com/lidanh/Pacman). They are well-documented, I built them when I learned Swing.

Good luck :)