# How do I assign numbers a graphic to be shown in a JLabel

Tags: java

I am creating a higher or lower card game, and currently, it generates a random number from `1` to `13` as just a simple string label (`1,2,3,4` etc), depending on what number gets pulled.
Instead of this, I would like to show a graphic of the card corresponding to the number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775373/java-how-to-add-image-to-jlabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int getRandomNumber(){
Random r = new Random();
int nr = r.nextInt(13);
return nr;
}
...
 JLabel label = new JLabel(getRandomNumber(), JLabel.CENTER);
```

To Update Label text you can use this method

```
public void updateLabel(int nr){

    label.setText(nr+"");

    //place this method inside your Jframe class extend from javax.swing.Jframe
    }
```

If you want to put an image according to the number. Supose you have an array of 13 images(numbers)//Image images[13];
then you can use this

```
public void setIcon(int nr){
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(images[nr]); 

label.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is adding an `Icon` to a `JLabel`.

You can do that using the `setIcon` method which accept any implementation of `Icon`, as for instance `ImageIcon`.

Something like the following should work:

```
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(URL_OF_THE_PIC));    
jLabel.setIcon(imgIcon);
```

and whenever a new card gets picked you can change text and Icon accordingly.